# Add Only 20 Most Recent Items From XML To NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, parsing, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am parsing a rather large XML file, and putting each item into a cell on a tableview.  After I parse the xml, it adds all the items to a NSMutableArray and then adds the number of rows based off the count of the array.  How can I set it up so that only the 20 most recent items get added to the array so it won't take as long to load?   My code when the parsing has completed is:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

    [_queue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        NSError *error;
        GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[request responseData] 
                                                               options:0 error:&error];
        if (doc == nil) { 
            NSLog(@"Failed to parse %@", request.url);
        } else {

            NSMutableArray *entries = [NSMutableArray array];
            [self parseFeed:doc.rootElement entries:entries];                

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                for (RSSEntry *entry in entries) {

                    int insertIdx = [_allEntries indexForInsertingObject:entry sortedUsingBlock:^(id a, id b) {
                        RSSEntry *entry1 = (RSSEntry *) a;
                        RSSEntry *entry2 = (RSSEntry *) b;
                        return [entry1.articleDate compare:entry2.articleDate];
                    }];

                    [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];
                    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:0]]
                                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

                }                            

            }];

        }        
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, wouldn't it help to add all the new rows at once? Just by adding them all to the _allEntries array and then reloading data instead of adding each row seperately to the tableview? That might really slow things down, especially since you do it animated.

As far as sorting the most recent 20 entries, you will need a way to sort your entries, once sorted just count the entries your adding and break from the for loop when you hit 20. For example:

```
int newCounter = 0;
    for (RSSEntry *entry in entries) {

       newCounter++;
       int insertIdx = [_allEntries indexForInsertingObject:entry sortedUsingBlock:^(id a, id b) {


           RSSEntry *entry1 = (RSSEntry *) a;
                                    RSSEntry *entry2 = (RSSEntry *) b;
                                    return [entry1.articleDate compare:entry2.articleDate];
                                }];

           [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];
//new code
           if(newCounter >19)
              break;

        }

    [self.tableview reloadData];
```

I am sure there are other ways to do it, but afaik this should do the job.  You could also take care of it in the tableViewController. In your numberOfRows function you can limit to 20 if the array is longer. Then you still have all the entries in the Array but you only show 20, in the example above you only store 20 max in the array and show them all.

Comment: Call me dim, but I don't see how this would do anything.  It seems you declare an int with a value of 0 and then tell code to break if it ever goes over 19, but never in code is it used elsewhere, so I don't see how it ever WOULD get different than 0.

Comment: You add one everytime you go through the for loop with newCounter++;

Comment: My bad, completely missed that line.  I apologize

Comment: Let me know if this fixed your issue though. Hope it did.